# Redirecting to the wrong URL laravel 5.1 authentication

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

I dont know what I did wrong here, whenever I type in the URL: `localhost/project/public/auth/login` it redirects me to `localhost/project/public/home` and therefore I get the error: `NotFoundHttpException`

Here's my route:

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('/auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('/auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');


Route::controllers([
   'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

and I've added those in authController:

```
protected $redirectPath = "/adminportfolio";
protected $loginPath = 'auth/login';
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/index';
```

Please can someone help me out here..

Comment: Well, you're being redirected because you're already logged in. You should be redirected to `/adminportfolio` though. Try removing the leading `/` from `$redirectPath`.

Comment: Yes thanks to @BrokenBinary

Comment: happened to me as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Find the RedirectIfAuthenticated file from in middleware, which looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    ...
    [----this file was truncated for simplicity----]
    ...

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

You'll notice the `redirect('/home')`, you may need to change that to fit your needs.